# LWE status versus modern deployed crypto

Tags: public-key, discrete-logarithm, post-quantum-cryptography, factoring, lwe

LWE is the one of the most promising post quantum strategy.

How does parameters (key sizes, time for encryption etc) for LWE compare with modern deployed standards such as Factoring or discrete log based solutions for various problems such as:

1. Signature,
2. Key exchange,
3. Homomorphic encryption,
4. authentication,
5. various other practical problems?

Comment: we don't have (fully) homomorhic encryption schemes that use factorization or discete log.